# DHCP client information request

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dhcp

I am calling the DhcpGetClientInfo function from Windows DHCP Server Management API. Below is a segment of code where I query the DHCP server(in my case a Raspberry Pi) for a specific client's general information. The necessary header files have been included and the program builds fine with no compile time errors.

```
int a;

DHCP_SEARCH_INFO SearchInfo;
DHCP_CLIENT_INFO* ClientInfo;

// Search criteria 
SearchInfo.SearchType =  DhcpClientIpAddress; 
SearchInfo.SearchInfo.ClientIpAddress = inet_addr("10.10.10.144"); 

a = DhcpGetClientInfo(L"10.10.10.1", &SearchInfo, &ClientInfo);

if(a != ERROR_SUCCESS){

    std::ofstream outputFile("C:\\Temp\\TestX\\log4.txt");

    outputFile << a; 

}
```

However, the function fails and returns error number #1722 which does not appear in the DHCP Server Management API Error Codes here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363378(v=vs.85).aspx

I cannot find any information on said error. Has anyone any experience to help me out here. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 1702: RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE: The RPC server is unavailable.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681386%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: You saw that the function is only supported for server operating systems?

Comment: Only just realised this... so I would not be able to employ these function on WIndows 7...only the Windows Server Operating Systems.... is there any equivalent function/library for Win7 or XP??

Comment: What information are you looking for? The mac address? You could try this one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thankyou for the link! I am looking to query the DHCP server for it's client IP addresses which it has assigned to client devices.. I was not sure how to do this in C++ so I found that function and implemented it. I did not realise it was for server-side only.. do you know any way I can do this in C++ ..?